# Segmentation fault caused by white space not caught in string from cin

Tags: c++, algorithm, segmentation-fault

I'm working on implementing the [Shunting Yard Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) to evaluate **simple** expressions. The code seems to work but crashes if there are spaces. This is surprising because there is a specific check for white space which seems to simply not catch it.

```
using namespace std;


mpz_class exprToTokens(string expression);
int precedence(const char op);
mpz_class applyOperation(const mpz_class a, const mpz_class b, const char op);

int main() {



    try {
    while(true)
    {
            cout << "enter an expression: ";
            string expr;
            cin >> expr;
            if( expr == "e")
            {
        break;
            }
            cout << "output: " << exprToTokens(expr) << endl;
    }

    } catch( const std::exception & ex ) {
       cerr << "message: " << ex.what() << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

mpz_class exprToTokens(string expression)
{

    stack<char> operators;
    stack<mpz_class> output;


    unsigned int i = 0;
    while(i < expression.length())
    {
        if(isspace(static_cast<unsigned char>(expression.at(i))))//skip white space
        {
            cout << "is space" << endl;//never happens
            i++;
            continue;
        }
        else if(isdigit(expression[i]))
        {
            unsigned int j = i;
            while(i < expression.length() && isdigit(expression[j]))
            {
                j++;
            }
            const string number = expression.substr(i, j-i);
            const mpz_class term(number);
            output.push(term);
            i = j;
            continue;
        }
        else//token is an operator
        {
            while(!operators.empty() && precedence(operators.top() >= precedence(expression[i])))
            {
                const mpz_class val1 = output.top();
                output.pop();

                const mpz_class val2 = output.top();
                output.pop();

                const char op = operators.top();
                operators.pop();

                output.push(applyOperation(val1, val2, op));
            }
            operators.push(expression[i]);
        }
        i++;
    }

    /*process remaining operations and values on stacks*/
    while(!operators.empty())
    {
        const mpz_class val2 = output.top();//something bad happens here when spaces are around operator
        output.pop();

        const mpz_class val1 = output.top();
        output.pop();

        const char op = operators.top();
        operators.pop();

        output.push(applyOperation(val1, val2, op));
    }

    return output.top();
}

int precedence(const char op)
{ 
    if(op == '+' || op == '-')
        return 1; 
    if(op == '*' || op == '/') 
        return 2; 
    return 3;
} 


mpz_class applyOperation(const mpz_class a, const mpz_class b, const char op)
{
    switch(op)
    { 
        case '+': return a + b; 
        case '-': return a - b; 
        case '*': return a * b; 
        case '/': return a / b;
        default: throw invalid_argument("syntax not recognized");
    } 
}
```

For example `3+3` gives `6` result but `3 + 3` causes a segmentation fault. Any ideas?

Aside question: the Shunting Yard Algorithm converts infix to postfix notation. So strictly speaking it's common to modify the algorithm to actually evaluate the expression, but is it still the Shunting Yard Algorithm anymore? For the normal algorithm isn't another algorithm needed to still evaluate the expression in postfix notation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cin >> expr;` splits the input at spaces, so three separate expressions are read: `3`, `+` and `3`. To read the entire expression, use [`std::getline()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

Your program probably crashes parsing the first one, because this loop does not check for `j`:

```
while(i < expression.length() && isdigit(expression[j]))
{
    j++;
}
```

Comment: Is isdigit('\0') false? Is std::string always null terminated (since C++11)? which should make the first expression irrelevant in this case.

Comment: @Surt is correct, `isdigit(0)` is false: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit